# PHP - DomDocument->saveHTML выводит в непонятной кодировке

Tags: php

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

На выходе получается обракадабра. Пробовал через iconv, тоже самое. Как сделать что бы корректно выводились и русские и латинские символы нормально?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать сделать так перед работой с DomDocument:

```
$string = mb_convert_encoding($string, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8")
```

Мне однажды это помогло.

Answer (score 1):

Надо делать так:

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML( mb_convert_encoding( $html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8' ) );
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Или последнюю строку заменить на такую:

```
echo html_entity_decode( $dom->saveHTML() );
```

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо указывать кодировку мета тегами в самом HTML:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument($html);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$nodeHead=$dom->createElement("head");
$nodeMeta=$dom->createElement('meta');
$dom->insertBefore($nodeHead, $dom->firstChild);
$nodeMeta->setAttribute ("http-equiv","Character");
$nodeMeta->setAttribute ("content","ISO-8859-1");
$nodeHead->appendChild($nodeMeta);
$nodeMeta=$dom->createElement('meta');
$nodeMeta->setAttribute ("http-equiv","Content-Type");
$nodeMeta->setAttribute ("content","text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");
$nodeHead->appendChild($nodeMeta);
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```